# CouchDb startkey, endkey doesn't works together

Tags: curl, couchdb

I am querying a view by:
`curl -vX GET 'http://root:root@127.0.0.1:5984/twitter_api_new/_design/tweet/_view/tweets_by_source?endkey=\["yoono","2011-10-09"\]&group=true&startkey=\["yoono", "2011-10-10"\]'`

This returns `curl: (52) Empty reply from server`

But if I remove either of startkey and endkey, then it returns results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`` `curl -vX GET 'http://root:root@127.0.0.1:5984/twitter_api_new/_design/tweet/_view/tweets_by_source?endkey=\["yoono","2011-10-09"\]&group=true&startkey=\["yoono",**_**"2011-10-10"\]' ``

Just removed empty space from `\["yoono",**_**"2011-10-10"\]'` array elements. **_** was the space removed.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding -g to your curl command. This disables curl's globbing.

```
curl -gv 'http://root:root@127.0.0.1:5984/twitter_api_new/_design/tweet/_view/tweets_by_source?endkey=["yoono","2011-10-09"]&group=true&startkey=["yoono", "2011-10-10"]'
```